# Stored procedure inside a trigger for logging

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, stored-procedures, triggers

I am using an identical trigger for multiple tables for logging DML events and because of that I have lots of redundant code. How can I write a stored procedure and call it inside those triggers to log data?

Here is what my trigger looks like

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [Person].tr_logInsertDeleteOrUpdateemployee
ON [Person].employee
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @tableName varchar(100) = '[Person].employee'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM inserted) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.DMLLogs
            SELECT updatedRecord = 'updated row', @tableName, ID, SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE()  
            FROM deleted
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM inserted) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.DMLLogs
            SELECT insertedRecord = 'inserted', @tableName, ID, SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE() 
            FROM inserted
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM deleted) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.DMLLogs
            SELECT deletedRecord = 'deleted from', @tableName, ID, SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE() 
            FROM deleted
    END
END
```

Comment: Triggers are expensive. I would have 3 specific triggers for each where the logging action is known with no need to repeatedly query the virtual tables. Also, have you considered making use of temporal tables which gives you a lot of what you already have and more.

Comment: @shoko- moko Using triggers will drastically reduce your performance and slow down your queries with a high number of users. It is better to insert the log operation when inserting or editing through the program. This is because triggers have to be designed in a very complex way during bulk insert or bulk update, and this causes performance problems in the database that you will encounter during development.

Comment: Perhaps a temporal table would be a better choice if you must do this within the database.

Answer (score 3):

Putting aside the question of whether there's a better option than creating triggers, the inserted and deleted virtual tables are not visible in a stored procedure, so there's not really a way to do that.  The usual practice here is to automate the creation of the boilerplate triggers so they are all created from a single template.  Something like:

```
create schema admin
go
create or alter proc admin.GenerateAuditingTriggers
as
begin
    declare c cursor local for
    select name, schema_name(schema_id)
    from sys.tables 
    where schema_id in (schema_id('dbo'))
    
    open c
    declare @tableName sysname
    declare @schemaName sysname

    fetch next from c into @tableName, @schemaName 
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat(
        '
        CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER  ',quotename(@schemaName),'.',quotename('tr_logInsert' + @tableName),'
        ON ',quotename(@schemaName),'.',quotename(@tableName),'
        AFTER INSERT
        AS
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON

            DECLARE @tableName varchar(100) = ''',quotename(@schemaName),'.',quotename(@tableName),'''
            INSERT INTO dbo.DMLLogs
            SELECT updatedRecord = ''inserted row'', @tableName, ID, SYSTEM_USER, GETDATE()  
            FROM inserted
        END
        ')
        print @sql
        exec (@sql)
        print 'trigger created'
        print ''
        fetch next from c into @tableName, @schemaName 
    end
    close c 
    deallocate c
end
```